# How to convince my hierarchy to optimize my remuneration scheme

Tags: software-industry, human-resources, belgium

I've been self-employed since I finished my education. Recently, I accepted a permanent position in a fairly large non-profit organization.

Where I work and live there is a particularly advantageous copyright remuneration scheme there. Basically you can have a significant portion of your salary ( up to 25% ) payed with that remuneration scheme if you can prove your line of work falls under the copyright regime.

When I joined I assumed that my remuneration would work in this scheme, it turns out it's not. As I'm working there as a developer I totally fall under the requirement for that scheme. I know it because I've been paying myself in such a way via the small company I own for freelancing purposes. But when questioning HR about that optimization they bluntly answered : "We never did that and have no plan to do it in the future". They refused to elaborate further. Which I find very weird considering that both the employers and employee benefit from such an arrangement.

I also questioned the union representative working in my team and he told me that HR generally behave like a brick wall and won't do any move, especially for such a small portion of the workforce; around 5 developers in a company of around 1500 people ( Other jobs in the same company might benefits from this though )

From my understanding there's nothing I can legally do to force them to do it, even though it would benefits both parties, which make the situation even more infuriating. What options do I have to convince them to apply this remuneration scheme ?

Comment: How does the firm benefit from the scheme?

Comment: Simply put the part of your salary that is payed with that scheme does not go toward your bruto, hence the company also pays less in employment taxes. @mattfreake

Comment: I discussed this with my direct manager, yes. He is very interested by the subject but also thinks that HR won't do a thing about it. @JoeStrazzere

Comment: This is tagged software industry but there are only 5 developers out of 1500 employees? How does that connect with the remuneration scheme?  Could you add a country tag?  That is usually important when talking taxes.

Comment: Seems unfortunate, but perhaps also not a hill worth dying on.

Comment: Non-profit organization do not work for profit, and usually are run by people more interested in a "cause" , hence strong and stupid HR departments. I suggest you start looking elsewhere, especially because software development is not their primary line of work.

Comment: Do you happen to live in Belgium?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever there is organisational change, you have to broadly answer two questions:

What is the benefit/risk for the business? What is the benefit for others that are to instigate the change?

In both cases, there is associated risk involved. You have to look at it from the perspective of the HR person:

- Will this change be easy to implement?
- Do we understand the legal issues around this change?
- Will it benefit the company in some sort of meaningful way?
- If this goes south for some reason, will I get fired?
- Is there a reason we are not doing this already?
- Is this a good use of my time?
- Is the employee worth satisfying?
- Will other affected employees agree with this change?

So, to instigate the change you want, you have to think of reasons that cover the above questions, and also recognise that you may not have great answers to the above questions.

If your boss is not willing to engage with HR, they probably do not think that HR can be convinced.

In any case, in the future, you should look carefully over any employment contracts, and not make any assumptions about renumeration.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very steep road. What you propose will only impact 5 people from 1500 employees. Companies shy away from optional things where the cost of setting it up, and keeping it around can exceed the benefits.

Lets do some math. Taxes are 10% of your income, this method you propose will make 25% of your pay exempt from those taxes. Therefore they can save 2.5% of your salary by making this switch. This means that they will save 12.5% of a person when applying this to all 5 of you. They can look at that and say they can hire an additional 1/8 of a person on top of the 1500 people they already have. That assumes there are no costs involved in doing this.

You need much more impressive numbers to convince the company. You need to know that many more employees can fall under this scheme. You will have to mention some like sized similar companies that are doing so. You will also have to address if being a non-profit changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Despite whatever advantages you're perceiving that the company may enjoy, you've completely overlooked the following:

- There will have to be someone paid to understand the legalities of the remuneration scheme as it exists right now and all forthgoing changes, ad infinitum.  This would seem to be not an HR-oriented duty, but more so a duty of an accounting department *along with* a legal department.  Who's going to pay for this overhead?
- How would your manager, or any manager, justify the costs?  If you worked for a software company, things would probably be different.
- It's likely that your company's payroll system would need to be modified as well, and someone would need to be trained to accommodate the changes in the way five out of 1500 staff get their pay.  None of this comes for free, my friend.

In practical terms, no one is going to spend a dollar to save five cents!

I hope you'll learn to think a bit more holistically, because the lack of doing so will reflect on you poorly in the long term.

Good luck.